# ruby on rails 4 - Wicked Wizard _Totally_ dynamic step order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

I've found almost what I needed in a previous question: [Wicked Wizard dynamic step order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271783/wicked-wizard-dynamic-step-order)

Unfortunately, I'm still struggling with my problem. I want to make my Wicked Wizard have totally dynamic step order (besides the first step). Each response is a database item belonging to each Question database item. I want to use the next_question attribute from the Response that is selected to determine which step will come next.

```
class ExperimentsController < ApplicationController
def create
  @experiment = Experiment.new
  @experiment.save(validate: false)
  redirect_to experiment_steps_path(@experiment, Experiment.steps.first)
end
...
private
  def experiment_params
    params.require(:experiment).permit(:name, :questions, :responses, :form_step)
  end
end



class ExperimentStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
before_action :set_steps
before_action :setup_wizard

def show
  @experiment = Experiment.find(params[:experiment_id])
  @next_question = Response.find(params[:next_question])
  jump_to(:next_question)
  render_wizard
end

private

def set_steps
  self.steps = Question.pluck(:name)
end

def response_params
  params.fetch(:response, {}).permit(:next_question)
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried a similar strategy in Rails 3.2 with `before_filter` it gave me an error that suggested I use `prepend_before_filter` instead, which worked a treat. It looks like a similar method exists in Rails 4: [`prepend_before_action`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/prepend_before_action), so that should work for you. Also, I cast the elements as symbols (not strings), so in your case it would be something like `self.steps = Question.pluck(:name).map(&:to_sym)`. Hope that helps!